# Using string from SharedPreferences in button to start new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

Hi and thanks for any help.

I want to create a "resume game" button for my interactive fiction (choose your own adventure style) novel.  Basically, each page is an activity, and the "resume game" button takes users from the MainActivity to the most recent activity they were on (i.e. most recent page of the book they read).

I have saved a class name in SharedPreferences as a string called "page", and I know I did this correctly.

**How do I retrieve the string from SharedPreferences and use it in a start activity intent?**

First here is my code for the SharedPreferences string:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("PrefFile", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("page", "Page4.class");
        editor.apply();
```

Here is the code for the button; how can I replace the ???? with the string saved under the key "page"?  (Currently, you can see that page=Page4.class).

```
public Button butcontinue;
public void init2() {
    butcontinue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butcontinue);
    butcontinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent gotopage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ??????);

            startActivity(gotopage);


        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
Intent gotopage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Class.forName(page));
```

do this:

```
Intent gotopage = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(packageName, page);
```

where `packageName` is the `package` entry from your manifest and `page` should contain the fully qualified class name, like "com.example.savegame.Page4" or whatever your fully qualified class name is.

Comment: YES!!!! YESS!!!!  Thank you, good sir! You have solved the problem.  3 days of torture are over thanks to your willingness to help.  You've made a random guy trying to learn code very happy!

Comment: Happy to be of assistance. You can accept this answer if it was helpful to you. Just click on the green checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Save the page number in SharedPreferences like this (without .class in value).

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("PrefFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("page", "com.example.savegamepractice.Page4");
editor.apply();
```

Then use [SharedPreferences.getString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method to retrieve the value. Also, you have to use the `java.lang.Class.forName(String className)` method which returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with the given string name.

```
public Button butcontinue;
public void init2() {
    butcontinue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butcontinue);
    butcontinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("PrefFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String page = sharedPref.getString("page", "Page1"); // Page1.class is the default string to return if key does not exist
            Intent gotopage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Class.forName(page));
            startActivity(gotopage);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I keep getting 'page' underlined in red.  The error message when I hover over it says "Cannot resolve constructor Intent" -- it looks like what it's reading is something like (MainActivity.this, java.lang.String)

Comment: Ok, I think I am closer.  It's now giving me a "Class not found exception."  What do you think the string should be?  Something like "Page2"  or "Page2.class" or com.example.savegamepractice.Page2?

Comment: try with the package name `com.example.savegamepractice.Page2`

Comment: I think my pages are all in the manifest.  When I created them, they should have appeared automatically, right?   In addition to the main activity, in the manifest are these lines:  <activity android:name=".Page2" />
        <activity android:name=".Page3" />
        <activity android:name=".Page4" />

Comment: And I have tried using the entire package name, but it didn't change anything.  I really appreciate your help, btw.  I have been working on this for literally 18 hours.  Trying to learn but just stuck!!

Comment: Also see the edit. Save it like `editor.putString("page", "com.example.savegamepractice.Page4");`

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("PrefFile", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

sharedPref.getString("page", "some default value")
```

If the "page" value doesn't exist, the default value will be the one that gets returned.

Comment: I do understand how to retrieve the string; I don't know how to use it in my method to start a different activity.